# Reticulate Knitting Error Using Seaborn (SVGLite not supported?)

Tags: r, r-markdown, seaborn, knitr, reticulate

I'm trying to knit an RMarkdown file but getting an error in a block where I am using seaborn.

```
ax = sns.countplot(x = 'target', data = df, palette = 'hls')
ax.set_title("Distribution of Positive Samples")

for p, label in zip(ax.patches, df["positive"].value_counts()):
    ax.annotate(label, (p.get_x() + 0.35, p.get_height() - 50))
    
plt.show()
```

The code above outputs the intended plot when I run the code chunk, however when I knit it, I get the following error:

Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : RuntimeError: Evaluation error: ValueError: Format 'svglite' is not supported (supported formats: eps, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rbga, svg, svgz) Detailed traceback: ..

Does anyone know why this is occuring and how I can remedy it?

Comment: Please provide a full reproducible example instead of a fragment.